# What happens during the Roslyn Binder phase?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, compiler-construction

I saw this [Roslyn Overview](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn%20Overview) and the Binder is explained as: "Next the bind phase, where identifiers in the code are matched to symbols."

Can someone please give a little more details about this, what exacly does the Binder?

Which identifiers are meant in this case, does it add a reference of the symbols instances to a AST identifier/declaration nodes property?

**Edit:**
Can you please give a little more details about the "matching"?

Let's say i have a NewExpression node with the (Type)IdentifierNode "MyClass", will the Binder then only check if there is a declaration for a type named "MyClass" or will it also store the found Type (Symbol?) in the NewExpression AST node so that it has a reference to the actual Type/Symbole instead of just a identifer/string?

Comment: The phase before the bind phase identifies the *declarations*.  Those declarations are used in the code, like in a new expression or method call.  Note how the declaration may appear *after* the usage of the identifier in code, the basic reason that two phases are needed.  The bind phase then does the job of matching the identifier in the code with its declaration.

Comment: I updated my question, can you please give more details about the "matching"?